# How to destroy a fragment and then create a new?

Tags: android, android-fragments, video

I have a fragment that plays videos, I start my application and everything goes perfectly, but when I press the back button and select another video file to play, my view does not play video.

**VideoActivity**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    A=this;
    th = Thread.currentThread();

    // OBTER URL DO VÍDEO
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null)
        _videoURL = extras.getString("CAMINHO_ARQUIVO");

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();       
    }
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
{
    static private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 700;// Mb
    static private final int NUM_FILES = 20;// Count files in cache dir

    public PlaceholderFragment()
    {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
        frame1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
        textureView = (VideoPlayer) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
        textProgress = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        textureView.setVideoPath(_videoURL);
        textureView.setMediaController(new mediac(A, frame1));
        textureView.setSeekListener(new VideoPlayer.SeekListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSeek(int msec)
            {
                //if (proxy != null)
                //{
                    //proxy.seek = true;
                //} // more speed for seeking
            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp)
            {}
        });
        textureView
                .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        textureView.start();
                    }
                });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in your code, you are creating the Fragment if the `savedInstanceState` is null. So, if the activity is not properly destroyed, you will use the same fragment.

Instead, remove this part from your `onCreate()` and create the Fragment in every time you navigate to your VideoActivity.